# Export in each loop in their corresponding folder?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list with directories.

```
shapelist
```

that has:

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\etg\\v1\\ASTENOT\\ASTENOT.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\etg\\v2\\ASTENOT\\ASTENOT.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\etg\\v3\\ASTENOT\\ASTENOT.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\etg\\v4\\ASTENOT\\ASTENOT.shp']
```

I want in each loop to use  each `ASTENOT` from the list above which resides in a separate folder.

I have solved this part.

The issue is how to export each outcome in the corresponding folder where each input (each `ASTENOT` in every loop used) is located.

Example:
I am using this specific function in the loop.

```
arcpy.FeatureToLine_management(['ASTENOT'],'ASTENOT_lines')
```

The `['ASTENOT]` position is for the input and
the `'ASTENOT_lines'` is for the output of the function.
How can I make the output exported in the folder of each corresponding input?

Example: the `ASTENOT_lines` of the first loop to be exported in  the `v1\\ASTENOT\\` location the second in `v2\\ASTENOT\\` and so on.

My attempt:

```
for i in shapelist:
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i],'ASTENOT_lines')
```

but exports everything in the current working directory and not in their corresponding folders of their inputs in each loop.

Comment: Try using an absolute path for your output. For example `arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i] ,i.replace('ASTENOT.shp', 'ASTENOT_lines'))`

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: From your description I assume, that the second argument to the `FeatureToLine_management` method is the path where the output file is written.
I suggested to provide an absolute path. For example `C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\etg\\v1\\ASTENOT\\ASTENOT_lines` for the first file.

Comment: You should make it an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I was able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an absolute path to the `FeatureToLine_management` method.

The absolute path can be generated by simply replacing `ASTENOT.shp` in the input path with `ASTENOT_lines`.

So you can change your code to

```
for i in shapelist:
    outputfile = i.replace('ASTENOT.shp', 'ASTENOT_lines')
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i], outputfile)
```